# how to handel error if soup dosen't find the class or id

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This website sometimes i find both tab1 and tab2 and sometimes i find one

```
<div id="tab1" ><div class="movieplay"><iframe src="youtube.com" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div> </div>
<div id="tab2" ><div class="movieplay"><iframe src="youtube.com" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I am using this code to handel the error if soup couldn't find the tab1 or tab2

```
result = soup.find(id="tab1")
result2 = soup.find(id="tab2")
if result.find(class_="movieplay") in result or result2.find(class_="movieplay") in result2:
    frame = result.find_all('iframe')[0]['src']
    print(frame)
    frame2 = result2.find_all('iframe')[0]['src']
    print(frame2)
else:
    print("link not find")
```

when soup doesn't find tab2 return this error

```
frame2 = result2.find_all('iframe')[0]['src']
```

> AttributeError: ' nonetype" object has no attribute 'find_all'

Can some tell me how can i print like if tab2 not find in the code "link not find"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
# result is node with id="tab1" if found, otherwise- node with id="tab2" 
result = soup.find(id="tab1") or soup.find(id="tab2") 

# If at least one found
if result:
    result.find(class_="movieplay")
    ...
else:
    print("No elements found")
```